# Are mergeFunction parameters being provided in a deterministic order in the toMap collector?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

I have two lists that I want to concatenate in a single list and then use `Collectors.toMap` in order to remove duplicates based on a certain field. There cannot be duplicates within the same list, only between the lists.

When it comes to resolving the collisions of values with the same key, I want to prioritize the items from the first list.

I can provide `(a, b) -> a` as the `mergeFunction` which only works if the parameters are being passed **in order** inside the `mergeFunction` parameter of `Collectors.toMap` but the documentation is unclear about it.

Are `mergeFunction` parameters guaranteed to be passed in the same order as the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the stream should be **ordered**, which is not always the case.

If you're creating the stream, let's say concatenating two streams produced from your lists (which would be *ordered*) `Stream.concat(list1.stream(),list2.stream())` then your stream would be *ordered*.

And in case when collector `toMap()` consumes an *ordered* stream, then it would respect the encounter, unless you don't relax this constraint yourself by applying `unordered()`.

Here's a quote from the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering):

> **Ordering**
>
> Whether or not a stream has an encounter order depends on the source
> and the intermediate operations. ...
>
> If a stream is ordered, most operations are constrained to operate on
> the elements in their encounter order. ...
>
> If a stream is ordered, repeated execution of identical stream
> pipelines on an identical source will produce an identical result; if
> it is not ordered, repeated execution might produce different results. ...

If you stumbled up on the phrase *"most operations"*, then you should know that the only operations that might not respect the encounter order of the stream are `forEach()` and `peek()`.

`collect()` operation **does** respect the encounter order (if any) unless it's applied on a parallel stream by providing a Collector which specifies the characteristic `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` (relaxing ordering constraint might improve performance while running in parallel).

Note that Collector returned by `toMap()` is **not** unordered, the only characteristics it specifies is `IDENTITY_FINISH`.

Comment: OK so implying that I meet the prerequisites of ordered stream, the `toMap` collector is a stateful ordered collector which passes the previous item and the current item (in this order) as parameters of `mergeFunction`?

Comment: @GuerricP If `toMap()` consumes an ordered stream then you would get a consistent result - *merge function* `(left, right) -> left` would retain the value that has been produced earlier.